# How to stop my WPF usercontrol from loading, if i have basecontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a BaseControl, of which almost all my controls inherit from.

Right now I am working on security and I want to block users from viewing certain items if they do not have access.

I am able to do so on the `Loaded` event of the base control, but this is too late, this meanse the whole control gets rendered, and then replaced. I would like to replace it before it renders

here is an example of my code:

```
public class BaseControl : UserControl
{
    public BaseControl()
    {
        this.Loaded +=BaseControl_Loaded;
    }

    private void BaseControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!userHasAccess)
        {
            this.Content = new AccessDenied();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works perfectly, but a bit too late, Is there a way that I can do this before the `Loaded` event?

Comment: You seem to be seeking for OnInitialized event.

Comment: the UI is not the right place to put `security` stuff. It is strongly recommended that you create the proper application `Layers` and put code where it really belongs, instead of mashing your entire application in `Form1.cs` as you would do in winforms.

Comment: @hedgehog if it was a snake... then was no-more!!!!! thanx a mil... please post answer so I can mark :)

Comment: Flip Visiblity=Collapsed instead of swapping out your controls

Comment: @HighCore... depends on whether or not you want your security model to be intelligent... and self learning... I don't like broad based comments on how one "Should" implement stuff, each application has its own unique set of needs. If your comment does not answer my question, don't post it.

Comment: @HighCore can you give an example of how to better display different content based on the security then?  It seems he doesn't want to just hide or not display the values, but to make the user aware that they are there and just don't have access.

Comment: @Patrick.... not a bad idea, but our access denied page is full of goodies to assist users. so we need to load it. but I will definitely make use of it in a few places on the system... thanx

Comment: @DustyRoberts sorry, NO. Serious, professional software is made up of different layers which take different responsibilities as opposed to putting everything in code behind. Regardless of what the "needs" of your application are, you should be using proper layers. Otherwise your code will not have Professional-level.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat "display different content" - that's done in WPF using `DataTemplate`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out following sites:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx

Also check object lifetime events that is what you asking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You want to override the `OnInitialized` where the constructor and properties are being set up before the `Render` happens.

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
  if (!userHasAccess)
  {
   this.Content = new AccessDenied();
  }
  base.OnInitialized(e);
}
```

More information can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx).